# SAS Call Execute returns a string with a dot instead of the variable content

Tags: sas

I have the following code:

```
%MACRO CALCU(DATE_VAR);
%get_filenames('./subgroup/groups',filenames);
data _null_;
        set filenames;
        by fname;
        %put go;
        if fname =: "&TIME_INTERVAL";
        call execute(cats('%nrstr(%ACTUAL_CAL)(',&DATE_VAR,',',fname,')'));
run;
%mend;
```

When I call it like this:

```
%CALCU(cq2014);
```

The string being called is actually

```
%ACTUAL_CAL(.,MINUTE15_group0.csv)
```

instead of `%ACTUAL_CAL(cq2014,MINUTE15_group0.csv)`

I was wondering why is it the case? is it that macro variable cannot be used in cat statements?

Comment: Do you actually have a variable named `CQ2014` in the dataset `FILENAMES`?  If so then it is set to missing.

Comment: Why do I need to have cq2014 in the filenames? I just wanted to set DATE_VAR equal to cq2014 and call it.

Comment: If you don't have the variable cq2014 then do not reference it in the CATS() function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAS macro processor is mainly just doing simple text replacement. If you write this line of code:

```
call execute(cats('%nrstr(%ACTUAL_CAL)(',&DATE_VAR,',',fname,')'));
```

The `&DATA_VAR` is going to be replaced by its value. So you get this line of SAS code.

```
call execute(cats('%nrstr(%ACTUAL_CAL)(',cq2014,',',fname,')'));
```

So the second argument to the `cats()` function is the variable named `cq2014`. So the value of the variable `cq2014` will be used in generating the string to pass to `call execute()`.  If the variable is not previously defined then SAS will make a new variable with that name and it will have missing values for all observations in the data step.

You should have seen a note in the log saying that `cq2014` was uninitialized.

So you could evaluate the macro variable as a string literal in the data step by using double quotes.

```
call execute(cats('%nrstr(%ACTUAL_CAL)(',"&DATE_VAR,",fname,')'));
```

Or use single quotes and it will be evaluated when call execute() pushes the string onto the stack of commands to run after the data step finishes.

```
call execute(cats('%nrstr(%ACTUAL_CAL)(&DATE_VAR,',fname,')'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I shouldn't have cats the macro variable. Instead, I should have done this:

```
call execute(cats('%nrstr(%ACTUAL_CAL)(&DATE_VAR,',fname,')'));
```